# Get string between two string with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that look like this

```
BLA BLA BLA "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMN" BLA BLA BLA BLA
```

And i want to get the string ABCDEFGHIJKLMN,i tried to do it with REGX:

```
html = html.match("\"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map\": \"(.*)\"");
```

But it always give me an empty string.Any idea what is the problem with this method?

Comment: A regex is an object with a special literal syntax, it is not a string, a regex is enclosed in `/regex/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it without the quotes:

```
html = html.match(/"url_encoded_fmt_stream_map\": \"(.*)"/);
```

the slashes tell javascript it is a regular expression.

Comment: I run this code on objective-c so i don't have stuff like this